# Javascript - Make an img element slide in from the left and fade in

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just as the title says. (I don't want any jQuery or other things, I don't use those, I'm just using pure JavaScript, HTML, and CSS). I need the element to fade in, as well as move smoothly to the center of the page from the left. I need this in JavaScript because the action should happen after someone clicks a button.

I've tried this:

```
if(selected_property[0] == 1 && selected_property[1] == 1) {
    var left = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        left = left + 0.05;
        document.getElementById("property1_img").style.left = left + "vw";
        document.getElementById("property1_img").style.visibility = "visible";
    }, 1);
} else {
    
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you've already tried ?

Comment: You should look at css transitions: [transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: I need this in JavaScript not CSS. It wont work for what I am doing.

Comment: Firstly, it can be done with css and button clicks - the click changes the class on the object and the transition kicks on.  Secondly, if you want to use javascript, then you need to include something like the opacity style to update from 0 (invisible) to 1 (fully visible)

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler than what you've tried. You don't have to create the animation effect, CSS transitions can do that for you.

You can use JavaScript to set up a `click` event handler that simply updates the [CSS `.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) of the `img` and uses [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate the effect.

```js
let img = document.querySelector(".fadeMove");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  img.classList.add("moved"); // Just add the class the updates the opacity and position
});
```

```css
/* Initial style moves the element just outside of the 
   browser window to the left and fully transparent */
.fadeMove {
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;    /* fully transparent */
  left:-150px;  /* Just outside of window to the left */
  
  /* 
     Indicate that all properties that are numeric in nature that
     could change in the future should transition to any new property
     value over the course of 2 seconds 
  */
  transition:all 2s;  
}

/* Style that will be added when button is clicked */
.fadeMove.moved {
  left:calc(50% - 75px); /* Middle of window (specific to 150px wide image) */
  opacity:1;             /* fully opaque */
}
```

```html
<img class="fadeMove" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/">
<button>Click</button>
```